# how to reinstall config files in /etc of a package

Tags: apt

If I want to reinstall the configs of some package `x` (i.e. files in `/etc`), how would I do that?

Does `apt-get --reinstall install x` always reinstalls the configs?

Other answers suggest to remove the configs first and then use `apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" x`. However, I don't want to do that for all of `/etc` because I want to keep my system in a well-behaved state as far as possible. I basically just want that it overwrites existing config files.

I also read about `--force-all`, `--force-confnew`, `--overwrite-conffiles` and the `UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS`, `UCF_FORCE_CONFFNEW` env vars. Some documentation is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/dpkg.1.html) and [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ucf.1.html), although I'm not sure if it does exactly what I want.

Comment: I disagree, because I don't see how the linked Q&A is specific to a specific file/package. I still believe it's the right duplicate question. The question includes an *example* of a package and a configuration file. The answer there is generic and holds for every package (step 3 in the accepted answer is a generic template). If that answer does not answer your use case, you should [edit] your question to include why it doesn't.

Comment: That's all new information not present in your original question. Please [edit] your question rather than posting comments with further requirements for an answer. That's how this site works.

Comment: It shouldn't be that difficult to use `find -exec` to automate @gertvdijk 's solution.

Comment: So don't delete. Move them.

Comment: And read the manpages before asking for documentation: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dpkg.1.html

Comment: @muru: That link is what I searched for, thanks. :) Moving them out-of-place is also not what I want (it might make the system unusable for important files in `/etc`). I want them to be replaced directly. Would `--force-confnew` and `--overwrite-conffiles` do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do:

```
sudo -s
cd /tmp
mkdir deb
cd deb
apt-get update
apt-get download package1 package2 package3
dpkg -i --force-confmiss *.deb
```

You can look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/82801/linux-how-to-restore-config-file-using-apt-get-aptitude) for some more ways.

Comment: -1. 1) No need to download and local-install packages. apt-get can download from the repository directly. 2) It will not work as indicated in the comments -- the configuration files should be removed in order for `--force-confmiss` to work.